# python xpath returns empty list instead of the value or text

Tags: python, xpath, tree, lxml

Following is my program, it returns an empty list, it should return the value 'Mar 17', please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

newline="http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/20microns/balance-sheetVI/2M"
try:
    page = requests.get(newline, timeout=5)
except requests.Timeout:                                         
    pass
except requests.ConnectionError:
    pass
except requests.ReadTimeout:
    pass
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
yrs = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mc_mainWrapper"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')                           
print(yrs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `tbody` tag in your XPath as it's actually not present in page source, but added by browser while page rendering. Just skip it:

`.../table[2]/tbody/tr[1]...` -> `.../table[2]//tr[1]...`

Comment: Thanks Andersson. That was perfect.